# installing packages for python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, mpmath

I have 2 version of python installed on my windows 10 machine. 3.7 and 3.4. I need to install some packages for my old python distribution 3.4. For some packages there was an executable file available and I could install those like matplotlib and numpy. I could not find the same for `Scipy` and `mpmath`. Also trying :

```
C:\Python34> ./scripts/pip.exe install scipy

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scipy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for scipy
```

does not work. Would be great if someone could help me installing those packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the binary packages of scipy for Windows.

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)

You can use `./scripts/pip.exe install path/to/binary/scipy.whl` to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a scipy version which is compatible with python 3.4, e.g. 1.2.3 : `pip install scipy==1.2.3`.